# extract first N digits from string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to cleanup some data, that has N digits in the begining of the string and some in the rest of it. I need to extract only that N first digits.

Here's an example string

```
1410{{data}} est un program56me de lв556Ђ™
122 datadatadata5654df sdfs989
123datadatadata5654df sdfs989
```

I need as result to get

```
1410,122,123
```

Comment: Is it only the digits that appear after a word boundary (why you're excluding the digits in sdfs989)? Or is it the digits that appear at the beginning of a line?

Comment: I do not need that digits because it's a cleanup. i need only first N digits and no other text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(\d+).*$/', "$1", $str);
```

Comment: That was the exact what I was looking for. Thank you @M42

Answer (score 3):

Try using this regex :

```
^([0-9]+)?
```

using the `preg_match` command.

It'll spot consecutive-digit sequences at the beginning of a string. :-)

**Example :**

```
function getInitial($line)
{
    $regex = "^([0-9]+)?";
    preg_match($regex, $line, $match);

    return $match[1];
}
```

Comment: As the other guys mentioned : `^([0-9]+)?` could also be written as `^(\d+)?`... kinda shorter... :-)

Comment: thanks that can be used with some manipulations , but not with preg_replace

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: `^(\d+)`. It will instruct the regex engine to start from the beginning of the string, match one or more digits and put them in a group. Any other characters will be ignored.

Comment: as a resutl i get the rest of the string, but i need inverse.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need at least N digits at the start of each line:

```
preg_match_all("/^(\d{3,})/m", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible regex could be '#^(\d+)#' : in addition to the php function `preg_match('#^(\d+)#',$string,$param);` $param[1] will return those numbers