# Regular expression to extract (only) the first numeric value

Tags: java, regex

How could I get only the first number from the strings below?
Regular expression should stop at space or first non-numeric character.

Examples:
6x2mL
7 x 5mL
100Subunits
2*5Kg

Comment: This appears to be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854123/regex-to-get-first-number-in-string-100-2011-10-20-142855).

Comment: What kind of language do you use? (Java, JavaScript, Perl, ..) It will result in slightly different expressions, e.g. different escaping.

Comment: Perl would be nice to use it from a linux console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will help you

```
String regEx = "^(\d+)";
```

**OR**

```
String regEx = "^([0-9]+)";
```

It will extract the first numeric value from given Strings.

**Output :**

```
6
7
100
2
```

[Same problem is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736931/extract-first-n-digits-from-string-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

For a single numeric character: `\d` or `[0-9]`, depending on your regex syntax. Add `+` after that if you want the first sequence of numeric characters.

`\d+` would give `6`, `7`, `100` and `2` in your examples above.

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
^\d+
```

will match the number at the beginning of the string.